# JSP getting attribute definition

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have Spring controller where I map some attributes to model and than display model information through jsp page... Problem is that all attributes (i.e. `${attributeName}` - this is what I get in rendered page ) are displayed as defined, without value. This worked just fine until now. I suspect that one of the libs are missing but don't know which one...

Thanks in advance.

Controller example

```
@RequestMapping(value="/entity", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEntity(@RequestParam (value="q", required=true) String q, Model model){
   model.addAttribute("q", q);

   return "viewName"; //this is jsp file name
}
```

viewName.jsp

```
${q}
```

When I call localhost:8080/controller/entity?q=string, output should be "string", but the output is ${q}

Comment: What error you are getting?? Also display some of your code that is having problem.

Comment: there are no errors, just rendered page with attributes instead of attribute values

Comment: Please show your JSP and controller so that I can understand where the problem is actually.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question with code snippet.

Comment: Check your web.xml servlet version is 2.5+; your EL isn't bring evaluated.

Comment: @DaveNewton `<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"`...

Comment: What changed, if it used to work?

Comment: We integrated HBase with the project, and because of that reorganized our shared libs... I think that caused the problem, but I cannot identify which lib is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Model model in your controller function use `ModelMap map` and then add your attribute in that map.

Also check in your jsp the page directory on the top. Is there any attribute in that tag like `isELIgnored='true'`, then remove that and then try using this.

I think it should resolve your problem.

Cheers.

Comment: I used your method, but previously I have rebuild each and every dependency project which, I think, at the end solved the problem. In any case I will mark your answer as helpful :)